# WPF C# Create VS-Like Projects

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, projects

Edit:

Let me rephrase my question to make it more clear. Sorry about that.

I am looking to create a project based application. For example, the project file could be called .proj but within that there are files associated to that project similiar to how VS does it (and they just open in a tabcontrol).

So when a user selects file -> open -> project and selects a .proj file all associated files with that project will open.

Hopefully that explains it a little better. Many thanks!

Comment: I really don't think I understand the question. Are you saying you want to create a [tabbed document interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabbed_document_interface) for a new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open a project file of Visual Studio in a notepad.
It is an ordinary xml file with elements PropertyGroup and ItemGroup.

References for files look in the following way:

```
<ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
</ApplicationDefinition>
<Compile Include="App.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>App.xaml</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>Code</SubType>
</Compile>
```

You can parse this xml, create a hierarchical collection(using an information about folders and attributes DependentUpon) and bind it with a TreeView.

Open tabs are stored in the file with an extension 'suo', but you can save them in a xml format too. After you have open a project, you should find open files in the actual files and add them to the TabControl.

Answer (score 0):

You should do that like PRISM does; create a panel of any type ans stick in it the TabControl empty. Every time you select a new project you simply Clear() the number of tabs in the control. WHen you add a new file, you will do that by creating a new TabItem. The file will be displayed, of course, inside the TabItem.
Is this what you mean?

Comment: I edited my question to hopefully make it more clear! Thanks for your response.

Comment: You need to work with the VS assembly that provides already all the necessary API you need.